# Vector multiplication clarification

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone clarify the following for me? Let $v$ be some vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and let $v^{\perp}$ denote a vector perpendicular to $v$. Then is:

$v^{*}v^{\perp} = 0$?

$v^{*}$ denotes the conjugate transpose of the vector $v$.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Where did you get the $v^\perp$ notation? I would more expect something like for $w\in v^\perp$ perhaps.

Comment: And why use conjugate transpose? All vectors are real, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since $v^*v^{\perp}=\langle v,v^{\perp}\rangle=0$, we conclude that your equation indeed holds.
If I miss something, please tell me. Thanks in advance.